# Can't use specific methods in Mapbox LocationEngine

Tags: java, android, service, mapbox

I was trying to set up my own navigation app, but i can't use the methods listed here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/mapbox/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/testapp/nav/NavigationActivity.java

In details i'm referring at `locationEngine.setInterval(0);` and `locationEngine.setSmallestDisplacement(3.0f);` , if used Android Studio complains that they're not existing.

I've added the references to the latest mapbox-services snapshot as stated in the homepage of the github project.

What i'm missing?

Comment: Hey, did compiling all the dependencies really help? I tried to do it as the answer is accepted, but it didn't resolve my problems.

Comment: Hi, for me referencing the correct repositories solved the problem and allowed to use the methods. Also i saw that the link is dead now and i'm moving away from that project. Sorry i couldn't help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the readme, the SNAPSHOT snippet is only suggesting one dependency when Mapbox Services has 7.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-ui:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

see [the documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/mapbox-services/2.0.0/getting-started/#selectively-compiling-apis) for more details.