# Mapbox Methods Not Recognized by Android Studio

Tags: android, mapbox

Getting a bit lost here: I need to update Mapbox's API from 4.x.x-beta to 5.x.x and a number of things, such as xml attributes' names, way of getting access token and location services has been changed. I dealt with the first two thanks to the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/wiki/Android-4.x-to-5.0-update) but cannot seem to make LocationServices methods work. Android Studio tells me that it cannot resolve methods such as `getLocationServices()` or `getLastLocation()`. Here's what my code looks like, that's what used to work with Mapbox 4.x:

```
package com.example.myapp.interactor;

import android.location.Location;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationServices;

import com.example.myapp.MyApp;

public class GpsInteractor {

    private LocationServices locationServices;

    public GpsInteractor() {
        locationServices = LocationServices.getLocationServices(MyApp.applicationContext());
    }

    public Location lastKnownLocation() {
        return locationServices.getLastLocation();
    }
}
```

So, as per [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/mapbox-services/overview/telemetry/#getting-location-updates) here ("Getting Location Updates" section), I should copy [LostLocationEngine](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/mapbox/libandroid-services/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/location/LostLocationEngine.java) class to my project. When I did so, it cannot access some of the fields from LocationRequest.java LOST API class, namely `interval`, `fastestInterval` and `smallestDisplacement`.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209459/cant-use-specific-methods-in-mapbox-locationengine) question with really similar problem and tried to compile several combinations of Mapbox APIs, but no luck.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try this : LocationEngine locationEngine = LocationSource.getLocationEngine(this); as they have said "In 5.0 we have made significant changes to the way developers get user location information"

Comment: No. Does it mean that I need to use LocationEngine in lieu of LocationServices in Mapbox 5.x?

Comment: Found this: https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/user-location/ and I may be able to work with that. I'll post an answer if I get this done.

Comment: okay sure I'd be helpful for others

Comment: Check the answer that I was talking about

Comment: Hey Nisarg, yeah it helps with that particular error, now getting bunch of other ones. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem :) and what kind of other errors you can share here if possible!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't modified the maps locationSource yet, 
`LocationEngine locationEngine = LocationSource.getLocationEngine(this)` will return the default LOST location engine being used. Starting in `5.0.0` LocationEngine replaces the LocationServices class. For example, to get the last known user location, you can do this:

```
LocationEngine locationEngine = LocationSource.getLocationEngine(this)
locationEngine.getLastLocation();
```

You can read more on the LocationEngine in the [new documentation here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/mapbox-services/overview/telemetry/#locationengine).

Comment: Thanks! It helped with that particular error, now getting bunch of others, probably unrelated. Is it possible that Android has issues inflating my MapView xml because of an invalid token?

Comment: Ok, nevermind, seems it was related to trying to get access token inside my MapActivity instead of in my BaseActivity.

Comment: Also worth noting: migrating from Mapbox 4.x to Mapbox 5.x I had to change <service android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService"/>
 to <service android:name="com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.service.TelemetryService" /> in my Manifest file.

Comment: You actually shouldn't even need to include the TelemetryService inside your manifest anymore, we are making use of Android Manifest Merging to handle this for you now in the latest version.